# Django url template tag incorrect for deployment subdirectory when using collectstatic

Tags: django, django-templates

I am deploying my django project under a subdirectory of my site, e.g.

```
http://example.com/apps/[django urls]
```

The problem is when I run collectstatic, a particular plugin I am using (dajaxice) uses the {% url %} tag to create the appropriate javascript code. Since collectstatic doesn't know about the deployment subpath, the reverse lookup is to the root url instead of the subpath. For example, it should be:

```
/apps/dajaxice/my_func
```

instead of:

```
/dajaxice/my_func
```

Is there a good way to change the way collectstatic does the reverse url without hacking the plugin? The only thing I can think of is to have one url specification for collectstatic that includes the 'apps' subpath and another one that does not for everything else. However, I cannot figure out how to change the settings.py when using collectstatic only. Any suggestions or alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to solve this problem. Dajaxice provides a setting to change the url prefix:

```
DAJAXICE_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'dajaxice'
```

By defining this setting, to include 'apps' in the subpath, we can get the url we need. The problem is this prefix must only be altered in the collectstatic command and not when serving a webpage. Therein is the rub.

The solution is to create another settings.py file, we'll call it settings_cli.py. It will look like:

```
from settings import *

DAJAXICE_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'apps/dajaxice'
```

Next, we must load the new settings file when executing commands only by changing our manage.py file. Line 6 will now read:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "MYPROJ.settings_cli")
```

where it formally refered to "MYPROJ.settings".

Now, when we run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

it will use our special prefix, but not affect the normal prefix needed when serving webpages.

For more info on mulitple settings files, a good reference is http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12.html